# str_extract in R to match a code combined of letters and numbers

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to extract an "ATC code" from a text string in R using the str_extract function in R.

The code, within the string, always begins with "ATC: ", then the code itself is a combination of letters and numbers strung together.

The current output is partially working, it's just I'm struggling to match "A07AX" as if I make the digit optional then it is obviously matching even less than required

Original dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

data01 <-
  rbind(data.frame(text = "abc (ATC: A07BA51) fdfv"),
        data.frame(text = "abc (ATC: A07AX) dsaf"),
        data.frame(text = "abc (ATC: M01AE01) dff"))

                     text
1 abc (ATC: A07BA51) fdfv
2   abc (ATC: A07AX) dsaf
3  abc (ATC: M01AE01) dff
```

Code to extract the ATC group:

```
library(stringr)

data02 <-
  data01 %>%
  mutate(atc_group = gsub("ATC:|\\s", "", str_extract(text, "ATC:\\s([A-Z]+\\d+)+")))
```

Current output:

```
                     text atc_group
1 abc (ATC: A07BA51) fdfv   A07BA51
2   abc (ATC: A07AX) dsaf       A07
3  abc (ATC: M01AE01) dff   M01AE01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are using `dplyr`, we extract characters that are not `)` and that follows the regex lookaround `(?<=ATC:\\s)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data01 %>% 
      mutate(atc_group=str_extract(text, '(?<=ATC:\\s)[^)]+'))
#                    text atc_group
#1 abc (ATC: A07BA51) fdfv   A07BA51
#2   abc (ATC: A07AX) dsaf     A07AX
#3  abc (ATC: M01AE01) dff   M01AE01
```

---

Or we can use `extract` from `library(tidyr)`.  We capture (inside the parentheses) the alpha numeric characters that follow `ATC:` followed by one or more space (`\\s+`).

```
library(tidyr)
extract(data01, text, into='atc_group', 
         '.*\\(ATC:\\s+([[:alnum:]]+)\\).*', remove=FALSE)
#                     text atc_group
#1 abc (ATC: A07BA51) fdfv   A07BA51
#2   abc (ATC: A07AX) dsaf     A07AX
#3  abc (ATC: M01AE01) dff   M01AE01
```

---

We can also `gsub` to extract the substring

```
gsub('.*ATC:\\s+|\\).*', '', data01$text)
#[1] "A07BA51" "A07AX"   "M01AE01"
```